# Shell script grep result group by file location

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a `grep` result that contain:

```
/abc/123:apple
/abc/123:orange
/abc/345:kiwi
/abc/345:pineapple
```

I want the output result as below:

```
/abc/123
apple
orange
/abc/345
kiwi
pineapple
```

is there any way to get this output; i'm writing the script in bash

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is likely because you haven't added the code you've tried. You mention writing a script in bash, if you've tried something, please add to question by clicking [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$  cat f
/abc/123:apple
/abc/123:orange
/abc/345:kiwi
/abc/345:pineapple

kent$  awk -F: 'NR==1||p!=$1{print $1;p=$1}{print $2}' f
/abc/123
apple
orange
/abc/345
kiwi
pineapple
```

Comment: it would be easier to understand `awk -F ":" ' {if(NR==1 || p!=$1) {print $1;p=$1;print $2} else {print $2}}' file`

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh it depends. for me, the line in my answer is easier to read than your suggestion. perhaps adding a linebreak between `}` and `{` would be better.